# Jest error Could not locate module .... mapped as:

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, quasar-framework

I try use `Jest` with `VueJS` and `Quasar framework`. I write simple test:

```
import { GetUserDictionaryDataComponent, Component } from '@/pages/configurations/components/';

describe('GetUserDictionaryDataComponent', () => {
  it('should get correct type', () => {
    const component = new GetUserDictionaryDataComponent(undefined);
    expect(component.getComponentType()).toBe(Component.LEAF);
  });
});
```

But It not work correctly. When I try run my test, I get error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:

    Could not locate module @/pages/configurations/components/ mapped as:
    /home/user/git/my_project/client/src/pages/configurations/components/.

    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^@\/(.*)$/": "/home/user/git/my_project/client/src/$1"
      },
      "resolver": null
    }

    > 1 | import { GetUserDictionaryDataComponent, Component } from '@/pages/configurations/components/';
        | ^
      2 | 
      3 | describe('GetUserDictionaryDataComponent', () => {
      4 |   it('should get correct type', () => {

      at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/@jest/core/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:472:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/pages/configurations/components/GetUserDictionaryDataComponent.spec.js:1:1)
```

But, I don't uderstand, why I get this error. I checked, path `/home/user/git/my_project/client/src/pages/configurations/components/` is correct, my classes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this:

```
import GetUserDictionaryDataComponent from '@/pages/configurations/components/GetUserDictionaryDataComponent';
import Component from '@/pages/configurations/components/Component';
```

and it work for me.

Answer (score 8):

For me it was the simplest typo. I was using

`"\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMocks.js"`
but my file was named `styleMock.js`

Hope this helps anyone

Answer (score 5):

Keep `<rootDir>` as is if you just want to point to you path where package.json is.

I thought I had a similar issue with my webpack. For me I did not finish reading the Jest docs and thought that `<rootDir>` was some sort of placeholder for my root directory path. It is not...

Answer (score 4):

Camel case Important

`import Component from @/pages/configurations/components/Component;`